# How can I calculate the amount of crosstalk/parasitic capacitance between two plates with different voltages across them?

Tags: capacitor, semiconductors, crosstalk

I will preface this with the fact that I am a nuclear engineering student, not electrical, but I am working on a senior design project that might as well be an electrical engineering project. We don't take a circuits course as part of our curriculum, so I am quite out of my element here.

We are creating a sensor on the nano-scale that will measure surface charge distribution down a via for a process mimicking that of semiconductor manufacturing. To do this, we are depositing alternating layers of silicon oxide with thin aluminum plates that will be used to measure charge at different distances down the via. The different metal plates will not be directly in contact with each other. The idea is that the accumulated charge on the side of the via will induce a voltage in the nearest plate. Since the charge decreases down the via, the voltage on each successive plate will decrease. Our concern is that these metal plates separated by very small distances of dielectric material will act as capacitors and have a lot of crosstalk.

[image: Cross-sectional diagram of sensor]

[image: Alternate view of sensor]

[image: View of a single via]

My advisor has tasked me with answering the simple question of "If we apply a voltage of X to one plate, what will be the resulting voltage on another plate?"

I have not been able to make any progress on this. It seems so simple, but I can't find any equations to use. I really haven't even been able to find any relevant example problems or similar questions. And my friends who do know circuits haven't been much help, lol. The problem seems to lie in the fact that the applied voltage is horizontal on the metal plate, not vertical from one plate to another.

I would really appreciate some guidance in how to go about this.

Comment: (1) At what level of education is this question? (what year of undergrad or is this postgrad?) (2) Has this problem been solved before and you are being tested? Or are you breaking new ground here? (3) Please draw up a careful diagram. The first thing anyone does is draw diagrams to help orient themselves and the question. I don't see a diagram. Just words. A picture (or two or three, etc) would be pretty important, I think. It should be added here.

Comment: Draw a picture of what you are inexpertly describing with words please.

Comment: Sure! I have a diagram I can put in. I was not aware that I could add one to the post. Thank you for informing me :)
(1) This is a senior undergraduate design project
(2) As far as I'm aware, this problem hasn't been solved. I've been looking for example problems that are similar, but I haven't had much luck.